# How do I change the theme of whole app in React-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-native

I want to change the theme of the app(say background colors) by selecting from a list of colors. I've tried saving the state in a reducer and applying the state to a new page.

> LoginView.js

```
import styles from "./styles";

class LoginView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      primaryColor: theme.PRIMARY_COLOR
    };
  }
  navigate = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
  };
  onPressGreen = () => {
    theme.PRIMARY_COLOR = "green";
    this.setState({ primaryColor: theme.PRIMARY_COLOR });
    this.props.onPressGreenButton(theme.PRIMARY_COLOR);
  };
  onPressRed = () => {
    theme.PRIMARY_COLOR = "red";
    this.setState({ primaryColor: theme.PRIMARY_COLOR });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: this.state.primaryColor }]}
      >
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.greenButton}
          onPress={this.onPressGreen}
        >
          <Text>Green</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.redButton} onPress={this.onPressRed}>
          <Text>Red</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.navigate}>
          <Text>Home</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onPressGreenButton: color => dispatch(loginActions.saveColor(color))
  };
}

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(LoginView);
```

> HomeView.js

```
class HomeView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: this.props.color }]}>
        <Text>Home</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    color: state.loginReducer.color //color saved in reducer
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
)(HomeView);
```

In HomeView.js file instead of applying backgroundcolor in the way I did, how to include it inside styles.container. Is there any way to access function mapStateToProps inside styles.js I've imported. I've used redux to save the state permanently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use redux outside of react component like styles.js
by store.getState() API in [redux](https://redux.js.org/api/store) 
but I think the best way to handle this is to create a wrapper component and apply them to it then use it everywhere you want

```
class MasterView extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: this.props.color }]}>
         {this.props.children}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    color: state.loginReducer.color //color saved in reducer
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
)(MasterScreen);
```

then on each screen, you want you can use it for example

```
class HomeView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MasterView>
          <Text>Home</Text>
      </MasterView>
    );
  }
}
```

another way is in styles.js

```
import store from '../store'

const containerColor=store.getState().loginReducer.color

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor:containerColor
  },
}

export default styles
```

Comment: I didn't get this. See in my LoginView page when I click on green button. I'm calling the function mapDispatchToProps to save the new color in reducer which is then used in HomeView page from function mapStateToProps. And I'm writing a style page for each screen. So how do I get this value of color from mapStateToProps to a styles.js file which is a pure Stylesheet component nothing else.

Comment: Yea I'm getting this one. but one problem when I put backgroundColor: containerColor, I'm getting an error as "Invalid prop backgroundColor supplied to Stylesheet container.

Comment: please log your containerColor value probably its an invalid for being a color

Comment: The problem is when I try to get the value of containerColor in HomeView page I'm getting that color. But when I try to do the same inside the styles.js page its just blank like this ' '. Why is that happening ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197926/discussion-between-maleking-and-vinay-narayankutty).